# Why is the Cursor set to 0 position after clicking button in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

When I click Button the cursor position is changed to 0 in the `onClick()` function.

In debug I can see that `Cursor.getPosition()` returns correct position when outside this `onClick()` but inside this function it gives me position 0.

It is as if it jumps back to top of the screen however screen element don't really move.

Here is the `onClick()` function which I use inside `binView` in a `CursorAdapater` for a `ListView`:

```
viewHolder.buttonIAV.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
                    { @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                       //int position = cursor.getPosition();
                        Log.d("CURSOR POSITION2", String.valueOf(position));
                        boolean isSelected = selectionArray.get(position);

                        Log.d("IS TRUE2", String.valueOf(isSelected));
                            if(!isSelected) {
                                viewHolder.arTextV.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
                                setSelected(position, true);
                            } else if (!isSelected){
                                viewHolder.arTextV.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                                setSelected(position, false);
                            }

                        }
                    }
    );
```

Why this behavior?

Comment: There is only one `Cursor` for your `Adapter`. All of the items use the same one. When `bindView()` is called for an item, the `Cursor` will already have been set to the correct position for that item. After `bindView()` ends for that item, it can be called again for another item, and the `Cursor`'s position will be updated for that new item. Basically, the position is always changing. You can't expect it to be at some particular position at any given time. The reason you're always getting 0 there is likely due to the `AdapterView` repeatedly grabbing the first item to do layout calculations.

Comment: This `onClick()` is inside `bindView` inside it position is always given 0 no matter on which row's Button I click. Just outside that `onClick()` but still inside `bindView` I get correct position of the cursor. 

I understand that views are re-used. I just don't get why positions are different.

Comment: The `onClick()` method is not called at the same time `bindView()` is called. You're only setting the `OnClickListener` there. When you actually click, then `onClick()` is called, but by that time the `Cursor`'s position has changed.